# How to destroy chatrooms for current_user with ActionCable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actioncable

I created a chatroom feature with Rails 5.1, the issue that I am having, is that I'm unable to destroy the chatrooms created by the current_user. How can I fix my code to destroy the chatroom and the users within the thread by the owner of the chatroom?

chatroom.rb

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chatroom_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :chatroom_users
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category
  validate :max_channel_check, on: :create

  validates :category, presence: true

  scope :public_channels, ->{ where(direct_message: false) }
  scope :direct_messages, ->{ where(direct_message: true) }
  scope :recent, -> {where('created_at >= :thirty_minutes_ago', thirty_minutes_ago: Time.now - 30.minutes.ago)}

  def max_channel_check
      if current_user.chatrooms.count >= 5
        errors.add(:base, "You've created the maximum amount of channels, please delete some of the channels you have open.")
      end
  end

  def self.direct_message_for_users(users)
    user_ids = users.map(&:id).sort
    name = "DM:#{user_ids.join(":")}"

    if chatroom = direct_messages.where(name: name).first
      chatroom
    else
      # create a new chatroom
      chatroom = new(name: name, direct_message: true)
      chatroom.users = users
      chatroom.save
      chatroom
    end
  end
end
```

chatrooms_controller.rb

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_chatroom, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  include ChatroomsHelper
  include UsersHelper
  # GET /chatrooms
  # GET /chatrooms.json
  def index
    @chatrooms = Chatroom.public_channels.page(params[:page]).per(40)
    @chatroom_categories = Chatroom.public_channels.page(params[:page]).per(26)
  end

  # GET /chatrooms/1
  # GET /chatrooms/1.json
  def show
    @messages = @chatroom.messages.order(created_at: :desc).limit(100).reverse
    @chatroom_user = current_user.chatroom_users.find_by(chatroom_id: @chatroom.id)
  end

  # GET /chatrooms/new
  def new
    @chatroom = Chatroom.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  # GET /chatrooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /chatrooms
  # POST /chatrooms.json
  def create
    @chatroom = current_user.chatrooms.build(chatroom_params)

    respond_to do |format|

      if @chatroom.save
        @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
        format.html {redirect_to @chatroom, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully created.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @chatroom}
      else
        format.html {render :new}
        format.json {render json: @chatroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /chatrooms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /chatrooms/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @chatroom.update(chatroom_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @chatroom, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully updated.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @chatroom}
      else
        format.html {render :edit}
        format.json {render json: @chatroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /chatrooms/1
  # DELETE /chatrooms/1.json
  def destroy
    if current_user == @chatroom.user
      @chatroom.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to chatrooms_url, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully destroyed.'}
        format.json {head :no_content}
      end
    end

  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_chatroom
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def chatroom_params
    params.require(:chatroom).permit(:name, :category_id, :chat_name_color, :user_id)
  end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "chatroom_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "chatroom_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "last_read_at"
    t.index ["chatroom_id"], name: "index_chatroom_users_on_chatroom_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_chatroom_users_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "chatrooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "direct_message", default: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "chat_name_color"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_chatrooms_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_chatrooms_on_user_id"
  end
```

chatroom_user.rb

```
class ChatroomUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :set_last_read

  def set_last_read
    self.last_read_at = Time.zone.now
  end
end
```

Comment: maybe you should try this:
if @chatroom.chatroom_users.pluck(:user_id).include?(current_user.id )
end

Comment: because you store the user_id in chatroom_users table so you have to check that out and destroy the related chatroom of that chatroom_users.

Comment: Ok, I will implement your solution and post back shortly. ActionCable is going up in flames right now. Its getting really buggy with my updated gem spec.

Answer (score 0):

In your Destroy action you have `if current_user == @chatroom.user`, not entirely sure `@chatroom.user` will bring out the correct info, but to give the creator of a chatroom the ability to delete a chatroom, you might want to add a `creator` column to chatroom table and save maybe the username, then in your destroy action compare `current_user.name == @chatroom.creator`.

Or better still remove the condition in the destroy action and make the delete button only be visible if `current_user.name == @chatroom.creator`